# I am getting the following error on running flutter create my_appName: "my_appName" is not a valid Dart package name

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, angular-dart, dart-pub

[image]

I have tried upgrading flutter to the latest version. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 36):

I was getting the exact same error. 
After Renaming my working directory as per the naming convention attached by the Flutter team [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/package_names.html) which @Rushikesh just mentioned. It worked for me.. 
The reason is that the Flutter SDK uses directory/folder names as packages names and I was using a hyphen in my directory name.
In your case `mybmicalculator` or `my_bmi_calculator` might work instead of `myBmiCalculator` .
Give it a try, that might be one of the errors.

Answer (score 17):

> Package names should be all lowercase, with underscores to separate
> words, just_like_this. Use only basic Latin letters and Arabic digits:
> [a-z0-9_]. Also, make sure the name is a valid Dart identifier -- that
> it doesn't start with digits and isn't a reserved word.

–from [the description of the package_names lint rule](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/package_names.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think your app's folder name has some capital letters, any digit at the start, or something like that.
I faced this as my app's folder name had capital letters and when I used all small letters the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a capital letter at the beginning of your app name like this: `flutter create Appname`. You may encounter an error if you create a Flutter app with a capital letter at the beginning. To avoid errors, always use this method: `flutter create appname`, without a capital letter at the start.

Answer (score -1):

in my case the android folder is missing and flutter create . is also not working how i fixed my problem is .

1. copy the android folder from any project.
2. re-open the project and everything works fine