# Flutter Create Signing iOS app for device

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, macbookpro

[image: show the terminal screen]

I installed flutter, no problems. I did not install android tools.
I'm working on vs code. When I create flutter with the command palette in vs code, the project is created, but I cannot access it on the terminal. I cannot install the project from the terminal.
Can you help me..

Comment: i found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757656/i-am-getting-the-following-error-on-running-flutter-create-my-appname-my-appna) which is similar with yours, rename your package to `flutter_code` might solve this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting the following error on running flutter create my\_appName: "my\_appName" is not a valid Dart package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757656/i-am-getting-the-following-error-on-running-flutter-create-my-appname-my-appna)